# Does RestSharp perform WINS lookup?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to connect to an API deployed on a Windows server that does not belong to a domain.

When I initialize my RestClient this way my requests fail. If I provide my machine's IP address, my request works properly.

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://MyMachine/") {
    Timeout = 1000
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```

My guess is, RestSharp only performs DNS lookup and not WINS lookup. Is my guess right?

Comment: Name resolution happens at a lower layer of the network stack. It is not RestSharp doing it.

Comment: WINS is a red-herring. What you should be looking for is NetBIOS Name Resolution. (WINS and NetBIOS are tightly related, but I can assure you that unless you have a 20 year-old box still running Windows NT 4 or Windows 2000 Server then you do not have any WINS servers involved at all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your input, it has been helpful to understand that I was on the wrong track.
I solved my issue by adding the following line:

```
ServicePointManager.EnableDnsRoundRobin = true;
```